# C# Как узнать какой код в определённый момент выполняется в определённом потоке?

Tags: c#, отладка, профилирование, benchmark

У меня есть необходимость написать профилировщик кода, который должен отслеживать то, какой код в определённый момент времени выполняется. Он должен выявлять узкие места, засекая начало выполнения определённого участка кода (метода или отдельной инструкции), собирая статистику по затраченному времени на единицу измерения. При этом он должен работать независимо от измеряемого кода, который не должен ничего знать о выполняемых измерениях. То есть в клиентском коде никаких событий, сигнализирующих о начале/конце измерений, или вызовов методов профилировщика, для этого вызываться не должно.
На уровне представления я думаю, что это можно делать, получая значение стека вызовов и работая с его изменениями.
Какие есть, возможно готовые, решения или хотя бы ориентировочные предположения как это правильно обставить в C#? Это требуется в контексте Unity, но и решение в общем виде быдло бы применимо.

Comment: В Visual Studio 2022 есть готовый профилировщик процессора и памяти, пользовались хоть раз? Есть телеметрия GC, много ещё всего интересного, что в современном дотнете работает, а в Unity нет, потому что она на базе фреймворка времён динозавров работает. Написать конечно возможно такое, но смысл в этом какой при условии наличия [готовых решений](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour)?

Comment: Смысл этого всего в том, чтобы иметь возможность при проведении тестов выводить результаты профилирования прямиком в интерфейс в сцене. Профилировщик студии - это всё понятно, но оно в студии. В любом случае благодарю за ответ.